Is it possible to merge 2 initializer_list?
In cpp we can construct objects of some classes with an intializer_list:
std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::string, int>> il = { {"CPU", 10}, {"GPU", 15} };
std::map<std::string, int> m = il;

But can we merge 2 initializer_lists into 1 then use it to call the constructor? e.g.
std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::string, int>> il1 = { {"CPU", 10}, {"GPU", 15} };
std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::string, int>> il2 = { {"RAM", 20} };
std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::string, int>> il = il1 + il2;
std::map<std::string, int> m = il;


std::map<std::string, int> m(il1); m.insert(il2);

You seem to be working quite hard at using an initializer_list as a container. That's not what it was designed for, so be cautious. Even if you get working code, it's going to be weird working code and other programmers are more likely to misinterpret your goals and misuse your code.

@user4581301 could you elaborate a bit more pls?

That said, here's some good documentation so you can more easily determine what is or is not possible.

When you go too far outside the box, even when you're right, you confuse people and confused people cause all sorts of trouble. What is your overarching goal here? Perhaps we can recommend alternatives.

Side note: This is an interesting question even if it turns out to be impossible (I cannot see a  good, general way to do this without compile-time template meta mind-freakery or macro wizardry) or a bad idea.

In  order to merge two initializer-lists you would need to merge the two referenced sequences. Which means you would need an appropriately sized backing-space with the right lifetime.
As the size is arbitrary, it would need to be dynamically allocated.
Additionally, there is no way to determine the proper lifetime.
All the problems stem from it being a lightweight reference type just like std::span, instead of a much heavier container.

Instead, consider using the first for initialization and insert the other elements afterwards.

In other words, the answer to the question asked is "no, it is not possible to merge 2 initializer_lists".
